# How to get missing dates from sql table using Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

For example I have 'wind' table and there are information created every 5 seconds except for a few days in a month. My question is how to get all missing days between first and last record?

Comment: There are not enough details here for anyone to provide a useful answer.  Please specify sample data showing the problem, and let us know what you've tried.  We need to know pertinent column names too.  I can say, though, that "WHERE NOT EXISTS (subquery)" will be involved.

Comment: general solution for such queries is creating a calendar table with all dates and then perform a left join between your table and calendar table

Answer (score 0):

$historyDate = DB::select(
DB::raw('select
DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y %m %d ") AS date
from api_winds group by DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y %m %d ");'));

My query is locking like this.
Then I can create second array with for loop with $historyDate[0] as start and $historyDate[-1] as end and subtract two arrays to get missing dates?!